# What is "No running" short for?

Tags: grammar

What is no in this instance? Adverb? Adjective? Determiner? I'm assuming no is short for something but when I try to unwrap it, the verb doesn't seem to fit. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72484/what-part-of-speech-is-no-negative-pronoun-adverb-or-something-else

Comment: I don't think _no_ is short for anything, but notices saying NO -ING could be thought of as meaning _No -ing is permitted here_.

Comment: There's no running away from the fact that there's no running water in that house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'No running' is a notice like 'No smoking', 'No swimming' etc. and we all understand these notices as ***You should not*** or ***it is forbidden*** to run in this area.

Also 'no' + -ing is an absolute negation so it can be explained by ***not one***, ***without exception***.

You can look up [here](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/no) at the entry 'no as an adjective' for more information and similar examples.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about absolute negation. That's what was confusing me. I kept trying to replace No with words but it wouldn't play well with -ing.